# How HibernateTemplate works internally

Tags: hibernate, spring

We are using Spring and Hibernate in our application and use getHibernateTemplate() method for all hibernate stuff. My questions are:

- How HibernateTemplate internally works?
- What is the difference between getHibernateTemplate().save(entity) and session.save(entity)? Which one is better to use?

I have already searched on this but yet not found any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is open-source - you can just download the source and have a look for yourself.

`HibernateTemplate` is nothing more than a light wrapper around the Hibernate `Session` interface, providing its own interface that's more consistent with the Spring conventions.

If you don't want to download the source, you can read it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.0.6/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java#HibernateTemplate).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate provides convenient methods that handle resource management (like transaction setup, as well as session acquisition) in easy to use methods. It also knows about Spring's declarative transaction management and can participate in a transaction.

however, at one point a few years ago Hibernate made it very easy to support similar use cases with a little help from Spring. Spring now offers support for Hibernate session-based access using AOP to acheive a lot of the same results.

See this blog for the proper way to setup that support and for a discussion over which approach. There is simialar support for JPA and its EntityManager.

http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/